# Anki - Where are the field names?

Tags: python, indexing, field, anki

I have a field name. I have a model id. I have a list of fields in a note. I would like to index this list of fields by the field name (`"Front"`) instead of the index (`0`) because that is more user-friendly.

How can I get a list of the field names for a given model?

#### MCVE

```
from aqt import mw
from anki.utils import splitFields

field_name = "Front"
model_id = 256

index = unknown_function(model_id, field_name)  # 0

splitFields(
    mw.col.db.scalar("select flds from notes where mid = ?",
                     model_id))[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this suit your needs?

```
from aqt import mw
my_model = my_note.model()
fields = mw.col.models.fieldNames(my_model)
if field_name in fields:
    index = fields.index(field_name)
else:
    index = None
```

Comment: From a database entry (or model id), how do I get a `my_note` or `my_model`?

Comment: Not sure, how about `mw.col.models.all()[model_id]`? Have you tried launching the debug window inside the Anki desktop client and experimenting there? My snippet needs a model object, but your question says you have a model_id. You can get a note with, for example, `my_card = mw.col.sched.getCard(); my_note = my_card.note()`.

Comment: `mw.col.models.all()[model_id]` seems like it'll work. I haven't used the debug window - all of my knowledge of Anki's internals (sans from this answer!) has come from picking apart the code.